# What connector to join/extend 1/4 in stainless steel fridge water line

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator, pipe-fitting

I am running about 6 feet short and need to extend [1/4 in stainless steel fridge water line](https://www.lowes.com/pd/EASTMAN-20-ft-L-1-4-in-Compression-Inlet-x-1-4-in-Outlet-Stainless-Steel-Ice-Maker-Connector/3190901) by attaching another hose assembly with 1/4" female swivel compression fittings at both ends to it's end

What type of union can I use to accomplish that?

Is 304 stainless steel necessary? Can't find anything cheaper and big box stores only have [brass](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DIAL-1-4-in-x-1-4-in-Evaporative-Cooler-Compression-Union-93285/100197676).

Would brass work just fine?

Comment: The water line you linked has female fittings. Why are you proposing more female fittings to connect them? That ain't gonna do. You also wouldn't use compression parts. Seems you just need a fifty cent male-to-male nipple. Please revise to make it more clear what two fittings you need to join.

Comment: rephrased my question

Comment: what is that 50c male-male nipple that you referenced. Can you link to it?

Answer (score 2):

The link you gave leads to a hose assembly with 1/4" female swivel compression fittings at both ends. One presumes you'll be getting another similar length of hose. In that case you'd need a coupler with a 1/4" male compression fitting on both ends.

This could be tricky for a novice to identify. It helps to realize that "compression" means it's designed to compress onto straight copper or plastic tubing. Such a fitting is often provided as a set including the insert, ferrule, and nut one would need when attaching to plastic tubing. That extra hardware disguises the core part you're after.

In your case the fitting looks like this...

[image: compression coupler]

... and you'll discard all the removable bits at both ends and simply attach your hoses to the main brass part in the middle. (photo: lowes.com)

Comment: Thank you!
I think the item you're pointing me to is: 1/4-in x 1/4-in Compression Coupling Union Fitting